# How to rendered a component based on condition <apex:outputText>

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I have an output text, i need to render this component based on a condition in visualforce page

Here I need not to show the  when noOfRecords equals to zero.

I tried using rendered="{!NOT(noOfRecords==0)}" in  but it is misbehaving even at right scenario (i.e even when noOfRecords is more than zero, it not showing the output text)

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!NOT(noOfRecords==0)}">{!(pageNumber * size)+1-size}-{!IF((pageNumber * size)>noOfRecords, noOfRecords,(pageNumber * size))} of {!noOfRecords}</apex:outputText>
```

[image]

Kindly let me know in case of any further details

Regards

Arun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not handle the logic in Visualforce.  Instead create a property in your controller.  Then you can set the property based on your logic.  You should handle all logic on the controller side instead of the view side if possible.

**VF Page**

```
rendered="{!!showText}"
```

**Controller**

```
public boolean getShowText {
     return noOfRecords.size() == 0;
}
```